# Antiforgery token validation failed. Validation of the provided antiforgery token failed. The cookie token and the request token were swapped

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, csrf, asp.net-core-2.2, x-xsrf-token

I am getting below error at AutoValidateAntiforgeryTokenAttribute

Error:
Antiforgery token validation failed. Validation of the provided antiforgery token failed. The cookie token and the request token were swapped.
Authorization failed for the request at filter 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.Internal.AutoValidateAntiforgeryTokenAuthorizationFilter'.

I have searched online and StackOverflow nothing helped. Please let me know what mistake I am doing here.

In startup.cs

```
       services.AddMvc(options =>
       {
            options.Filters.Add(new AutoValidateAntiforgeryTokenAttribute());
       }).SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2);

       services.AddCors(options =>
       {
           options.AddPolicy("AllowAllOrigins",
               builder => { builder.AllowAnyOrigin(); });
       });

       services.AddAntiforgery(options =>
       {
           options.HeaderName = "X-XSRF-TOKEN";
           options.SuppressXFrameOptionsHeader = false;
       });
```

And I am setting cookie as below

```
 var tokens = _antiforgery.GetAndStoreTokens(_httpContextAccessor.HttpContext);

 Response.Cookies.Append("XSRF-TOKEN", tokens.CookieToken,
                new CookieOptions { HttpOnly = false });
            Response.Cookies.Append("X-CSRF-FORM-TOKEN", tokens.RequestToken,
                new CookieOptions { HttpOnly = false });
```

From the developer window, I am able to see the values are been set properly

[image]

In request header same value is passing

[image]